# Edit the windows explorer context menu for only a single user

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, contextmenu, explorer

I have a requirement where I have to generate new context menus by adding keys to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/shell` paths of the registry, but this alters the context menus for all users (as the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is edited). I am currently looking for a way to alter the context menus for only the specific (or more precisely, the current) user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Drive\shell`.

> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under both the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER keys. The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes key contains default settings that can apply to all users on the local computer. The [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes key contains settings that apply only to the interactive user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key). The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the majority of content on the internet -- in terms of advice in forums and blog posts and shared .reg files -- is guilty of propagating an outdated understanding of HKCR. "Software\Classes" should never be modified via HKCR, because the result is undefined depending on which keys already exist in HKCU and HKLM. The outdated advice originates in the era of Windows 9x and NT 4, before HKCR became a merged view in Windows 2000.

Comment: Didn't work. I had to add the context menu registry keys to this path instead: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell`.

Comment: @rajndev That is a different menu, Background is the menu inside the folder.

Comment: @Anders Which context menu does the path `Drive\shell` target?

Comment: @rajndev When you right-click a drive in My Computer.